# Learning SQL: Using a Declared INT to return a specific value from a separate table to then use in a where function

Tags: sql

I'm learning the basics of SQL and using SQL climber to do so, so apologises though this is really simple but I've been trying to solve this for a few hours.

The issue is I can return the data correctly by typing in 'Italy' but I need to use the INT to bring back the country ID for Italy. How could I go about this? or is there an easier way to do this that I'm missing

```
DECLARE @TouristAttractionId INT = 8

Select 
    'City' = ci.Name,
    'Attraction' = ta.Name,
    'Description' = ta.Description
from city ci
join Country c on c.Id = ci.CountryId
join TouristAttraction ta on ta.CityId = ci.Id

where c.Name = 'Italy'

Union

Select 
    'City' = ci.Name,
    'Attraction' = ta.Name,
    'Description' = ta.Description
from city ci
join Country c on c.Id = ci.CountryId
join TouristAttraction ta on ta.CityId = ci.Id

where ta.Id =@TouristAttractionId

order by ci.Name, ta.Name asc

Answer :

SELECT 
    City = ci2.Name
   ,Attraction = ta2.Name
   ,ta2.Description
FROM TouristAttraction ta1
JOIN City ci1 ON ci1.Id = ta1.CityId
JOIN City ci2 ON ci2.CountryId = ci1.CountryId
JOIN TouristAttraction ta2 ON ta2.CityId = ci2.Id
WHERE ta1.Id = @TouristAttractionId
ORDER BY ci2.Name, ta2.Name
```

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: No need to do a UNION here. Simply OR the two WHERE clauses' conditions.

Comment: Hi jarlh, if I don't use the union I only have a single line of data return where I want all the tourist attractions for Italy to be returned. I have to use the declared INT to get the country and this is the part I'm stuck as I'm not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    City = ci2.Name
   ,Attraction = ta2.Name
   ,ta2.Description

FROM TouristAttraction ta1

JOIN City ci1 ON ci1.Id = ta1.CityId
JOIN City ci2 ON ci2.CountryId = ci1.CountryId
JOIN TouristAttraction ta2 ON ta2.CityId = ci2.Id

WHERE ta1.Id = @TouristAttractionId

ORDER BY ci2.Name, ta2.Name
```

this is the answer by creating duplicate tables with additional join's within them